# Unable to run Apache Tomcat on my Windows 7 machine

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I'm unable to run Apache Tomcat on my Windows 7 machine.

Environment variables are setup as:

> set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111 set
>   CATALINA_HOME=C:\Program
>   Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.75-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.75 set
>   PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin

When I run startup.bat, I got the message:

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56" and the
>   tomcat console closes instantly.

Comment: When you run `startup.bat`, do you just double-click it, or do you run it from command-line? If you double-click, then yeah it'll close on error, but running from command-line shouldn't do that.

Comment: Also, just in case there is another Java version already on the PATH, you should add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin` to the beginning of the PATH, not the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your environment variables are not well configured or are not being used. You have intended to set the tomcat to

```
 C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.75-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.75
```

but the error message points to

```
 C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56
```

I suggest to review the configuration of the variables, and start tomcat from command line to see all errors.

Alternatively you can set the content of environment variables in `%TOMCAT_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat`

```
 set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have two different versions of Apache Tomcat in your Windows machine.

The environment variable CATALINA_HOME has been set to point **apache-tomcat-7.0.75**, where as the error has **apache-tomcat-7.0.56** in the message.

Can you please confirm in case two different versions do not exist in your machine.